# multiple rotation on ImageView

Tags: rotation, android-imageview, android

I want to rotate my ImageView 2 times

Initially it will rotate 360 degree and after that extra some degree..

I am using following code

```
protected void rotation(int start, int end, int time) {
    Animation a = new RotateAnimation((float)start, (float)end,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
    a.setDuration((long)time);
    a.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    a.setFillAfter(true);
    ImageView.startAnimation(a);
}
```

My problem is 
I am calling this function 2 times so it doesn't waits for first and directly starts second rotation.

**I want to wait until first rotation completes and then start second rotation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a Listener in first animation

```
a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    callNewAnimation();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
```